# HtmlUnit клик по элементу и выполнение JS скрипта

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

Есть сайт, на нем поле ввода которое после клика на него выкидывает меню. Меню подгружается JS скриптом.

Мне программно надо нажать на данное поле ввода и после подгрузки меню JS скриптом - извлечь html код страницы(с этим меню).

Пытаюсь это воспроизвести с помощью HtmlUnit, вот код

```
    @Test
    public void testPage() {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true); 
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://olx.ua/");
        assertEquals("Доска объявлений OLX, раньше Slando: сайт частных объявлений в Украине - купля/продажа б/у товаров на OLX.ua", page.getTitleText());

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
        HtmlInput input = page.getHtmlElementById("cityField");
        input.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
        input.focus();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
        String htmlCode = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(htmlCode);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вроде делаю все правильно, но в консоль я получаю только статическую версию страницы, без меню(а меню я ищу через CTRL+F по классу/id в консоли).

Как можно решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlUnit легок и удобен, но далеко не полон. Если у вас достаточно сложный JS, то лучше использовать полноценный Selenium. Будут легкие правки в зависимостях и инициализации. Потребуется больше памяти.

Comment: С Selenium сделал за 5 минут все, это очень круто! Спасибо огромное!